# Get existing CfnDBCluster with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

Using the CDK is it possible to get an existing CfnDBCluster to make modifications to?

I have an `AWS::RDS::DBCluster` in CloudFormation whose TimeoutAction I want to change (CloudFormation doesn't support it and I don't want to use the AWS cli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDK doesn't natively support importing existing resources for modification.

https://medium.com/@visya/how-to-import-existing-aws-resources-into-cdk-stack-f1cea491e9

This article describes using CDK to generate the template, then use the AWS Management Console to import the resource into the stack.

Here is an issue to track the support within CDK itself: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk-rfcs/issues/52

In your case, specifically since DB Clusters support this, you could create snapshot of the database then delete it.  Then reference the snapshot id when creating recreating the cluster with CDK.  Obviously it would require downtime though.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.DatabaseClusterFromSnapshot.html